# HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeValue"] is null with IE but works fine on Chrome

Tags: asp.net, session, internet-explorer, iis, webforms

I have been working with Asp.Net webform application,

01) Form1.aspx.cs -> Link `<a target="_Blank" class="ChapterLink" href="ViewFiles.aspx?MediaID=1&amp;ContentType=Media">`

ViewFiles has 2 options if MediaID is 1 then it plays video from IIS directory. if 2 then loads url from DB and streams video from Azure.

**Issue:**
when i try to open link with media id 2 (playing azure video) and coming back to Form1.aspx.cs and refresh my session becomes null (`HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeValue"] == Null`). this happens with IE11 but works fine on all the remaining browsers.

I had tried to update my web.config with

```
<sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
```

as suggested by [Asp.net session is null when using IE 10 but works okay on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523776/asp-net-session-is-null-when-using-ie-10-but-works-okay-on-chrome) but still it fails.

can anyone help me with a suggestion.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In IE browser tools, open the Internet Options, in the privacy tab, click the Advanced button to check whether you have selected the "Always allow session cookies" checkbox. Besides, try to change the session state mode to [StateServer or SQLServer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net).

Comment: tried but not working